# Uisplitviewcontroller navigation bar

Tags: ipad

How to hide the navigation Bar in detailView of splitviewcontroller in landscape mode??

In detail view,i tried like this

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding "self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES" in viewDidAppear worked for me.